# Code to Switch to another java class on android java

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a java class that loads the first xml layout and the second java class that loads another xml. layout
If I am about to switch from my first java class to the second one using code. How would I do it?

Comment: Are the classes Activity's or Services or regular Java classes? What do you mean 'I am about to switch form my first java class to the second one using code'? Do you mean you want to start one Activity from another Activity? Please clarify your question.

Comment: forgot to mention. Activities. yes that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use intents to switch activities.

You can create a new Intent that specifies the class to launch, and fire this intent. This will load your other activity.

Something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherClass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is there any other code? I used Intent an it force closed. thanks

Comment: If it force closed please post some of your code and your LogCat output so we can see what you're doing wrong and help you fix it

Comment: Yes as @Vicki said if you can put some code then we can help you and show you where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean start one Activity from another, you would do the following in Activity1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```